# Why can't I use printf format for replace a substring in a string?

Tags: c, replace, printf

I'm trying to substitute/replace a substring in a larger string using `printf` family functions, but don't know why it doesn't work.

```
uint64_t end = 100000;
char *bigchar = "This is a try $TIME_ELAPSED to replace using sprintf";
char *pPos = strstr(bigchar, "$TIME_ELAPSED");
sprintf(pPos, " %7ld ms. ", end);
```

But I get a segmentation fault in `sprintf` line (fails the `memcpy`), Both, `$TIME_ELAPSED` and `%7ld ms.` has 13 char length.

Also, changing `sprintf` with this one gets a segmentation fault too.

```
sprintf(bigchar, "%.*s% 7ld ms. %s", (int)(pPos-bigchar), bigchar, end, pPos+13 );
```

Comment: try `char bigchar[] = "This is a try $TIME_ELAPSED to replace using sprintf";`

Comment: BTW: potentially incorrect format specifier.  Use `#include <inttypes.h> sprintf(pPos, " %7" PRIu64 " ms. ", end);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pPos` points to a location in the `bigchar` buffer, and this buffer is read-only because it contains string literal. In `sprintf` call you try to modify this read-only buffer.

Comment: So, to fix it I must malloc bigchar and fills with data first. Like: `code` char *bigchar = malloc(100); sprintf(bigchar, "This is a try $TIME_ELAPSED to replace using sprintf"; `code` should work

Comment: You don't need malloc, you can use a plain array. char bigchar[] = " ...";.

Comment: Thanks to all, Wojtek, nos, pmg

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s="Hai how are you!";
```

string literals always stores in a read only memory.

Any attempt to change that will give the segmentation fault.

```
s[4]='q'; // This gives seg fault
```

But you can do like this

```
char *bigchar = "This is a try $TIME_ELAPSED to replace using sprintf";
char temp[100];
strcpy(temp,bigchar );
char *pPos = strstr(temp, "$TIME_ELAPSED");
sprintf(pPos, " %7ld ms. ", end) can
```

Comment: This is mis-leading.  `s[4]='q';` is perfectly fine.  `char s[]` is _not_ in read only memory.  `s` is an array of `char` with size 17 initialized with `'H', 'a', ... '!', '\0'`. The string "Hai how are you!" used to initialize `s` may exist in read-only memory, but that is implementation dependent.

Comment: @chux You are right chux. But i have changes the array of char to pointer to char. Hope now it gives seg fault. Thanks for the correction